# Magento rest api "create method" request

Tags: php, xml, api, rest, magento

I have implemented rest service. I have created `api2.xml` .

My code for api2.xml is: `app/code/community/Test/Hellorestapi/etc/api2.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<api2>
    <resource_groups>
        <helloapi translate="title" module="Test_Hellorestapi">
            <title>HelloWorld API</title>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
        </helloapi>
    </resource_groups>
    <resources>
        <helloapi translate="title" module="Test_Hellorestapi">
            <group>helloapi</group>
            <model>helloapi/api2_helloworld</model>
            <title>Hello World Testing</title>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            <privileges>
                <admin>
                    <create>1</create>
                    <retrieve>1</retrieve>
                </admin>
            </privileges>
            <attributes>
                <hello>Hello World</hello>
            </attributes>
            <routes>
                <route>
                    <route>/helloworld/test</route>
                    <action_type>collection</action_type>
                </route>
            </routes>
            <versions>1</versions>
        </helloapi>
    </resources>
</api2>
```

My code for V1.php is `app/code/community/Test/Hellorestapi/Model/Api2/Helloworld/Rest/Admin/V1.php` :-

```
class Test_Hellorestapi_Model_Api2_Helloworld_Rest_Admin_V1 extends Test_Hellorestapi_Model_Api2_Helloworld 
{
  protected function _retrieveCollection() 
  {
   return  json_encode(array("testing","hello"));
  }

  protected function _multicreate(array $helloData)
  {
    print_r($helloData);die('in create');
    return  json_encode(array("testing","hello"));
  }

  protected function _delete(array $helloData)
  {
     print_r($helloData);die('haha');
   return  json_encode(array("testing","hello"));
  }

}
```

My rest client which is calling the create method request is :

```
<?php

 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project    Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */


  $consumerKey = 'wgyygksagan0wmmp0qn5d5e9l9zwxwbg'; // from Admin   Panel's &quot;REST - OAuth Consumers page&quot;
 $consumerSecret = 'i0ccmp1dasbzk1bb64wphhl88sjwmiyj'; // from Admin Panel's &quot;REST - OAuth Consumers page&quot;
  // Set the OAuth callback URL to this script since it contains the logic
 // to execute *after* the user authorizes this script to use the Coupon    AutoGen API
 $callbackUrl = "http://127.0.0.1/magento/hello_testing_rest.php";

 // Set the URLs below to match your Magento installation
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl =    "http://127.0.0.1/magento/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
   $adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1/magento/admin/oauth_authorize';
   $accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1/magento/oauth/token';
   $apiUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1/magento/api/rest';

   session_start();

   if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1)
    {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
    echo "try";
    }

try {
     $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
     $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret,  OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
     $oauthClient->enableDebug();


     if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {

    $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
    $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
    $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
    header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
    exit;
} else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
    $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
    $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
    $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
    $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
    header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
    exit;
} else {

    // We have the OAuth client and token. Now, let's make the API call.
    $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);

    $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/helloworld/test?type=rest";
    $helloData = json_encode(array(
        'name' => 'hello world',
    ));
    $headers = array('Accept' => 'application/json,*/*;q=0.8', 'Content-Type' => 'application/json');


    $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, $helloData, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST, $headers);
    echo 'response<pre>';
    print_r($oauthClient->getLastResponseInfo());
    $data = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse(), true);


    echo "Data is:<br/>" . $data;
}

session_destroy();
 } catch (OAuthException $e) {

print_r($e->getMessage());
//echo "<br/>";
//print_r($e->lastResponse);
 }
```

Now on calling the rest client script, I am getting an error

> "Invalid auth/bad request (got a 405, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a
>   redirect)".

I suppose the output to be die giving "in create" and printing hello world array.My question is that what I am doing wrong in sending POST request by oauth.How to send request to "_multicreate method".

Comment: I hope the `$consumerKey` and `$consumerSecret` is a fake one!